# Datatables and ASP.net - HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

My datatables request is taking a too long URL as shown below:

`http://localhost:12527/MyHandler.ashx?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D= ... And a long url here...`

And i'm getting the HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found. Is there a way to remove these unecessary parameters to allow server proccess DataTables request?

Comment: Maybe use POST instead of GET for the data? Otherwise it is really hard to tell without more code / explanation

Comment: `$('#tbTransactions').DataTable({
 "serverSide": true,
 "order": [[0, "asc"]],
 "destroy": true,
 "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
  $.unblockUI();
 },
 "ajax": {
  "url": "/handlers/GetTransactions.ashx,
  "data": function (d) {
  }
 },
});`

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action from HTTP GET to HTTP POST.